# What happens when a promise is resolved multiple times

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

What is the standard behaviour if a ES6 promise is rejected / resolved multiple times?

The following code was only resolved once in `Google Chrome`, is this the standard behaviour in all browsers?

```
new Promise(function(e) {
    $('#button').click(function(){
        resolve();
    });
});
```

I have seen a [promise polyfill](https://gist.github.com/unscriptable/814052) throwing an exception on trying to resolve an already resolved promise. Does the specification for es6-promise specify this, or isn't the polyfill standard compliant?

**Update**

Sorry, I just realized that it is not a polyfill, but just a minimal implementation of a Promise (non standard).

Comment: upshot of the answers is, don't use that unnamed polyfill as it isn't "standard"

Comment: Are you sure the promise library you saw was a polyfill? There were multiple promise libraries **before** the ES2015 standard built promises into JavaScript.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A promise cannot be resolved or settled more than once. Once the promise is resolved, fulfilled, or rejected, further calls to resolve or settle it are ignored. *(If those terms are unfamiliar or only vaguely-familiar, I've written about promise terminology [on my blog](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/).)* No error is raised.

> I have seen a promise polyfill throwing an exception on trying to resolve an already resolved promise. Does the specification for es6-promise specify this...?

No. This is covered in [Promise Resolve Functions](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise-resolve-functions), which says what they do. Here are the first few steps:

> When a promise resolve function is called with argument resolution, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *F* be the active function object.
> 2. Assert: *F* has a [[Promise]] internal slot whose value is an Object.
> 3. Let *promise* be *F*.[[Promise]].
> 4. Let *alreadyResolved* be F.[[AlreadyResolved]].
> 5. **If *alreadyResolved*.[[Value]] is true, return undefined.**

*(my emphasis)*

There are folks who argue that attempting to resolve or settle a promise that is already resolved or settled should be an error. Since that didn't make it into the spec for ES2015, it probably will never be added, as it wouldn't be backward-compatible with existing code.

Comment: hi @T.J. Crowder excellent+1, we can say that **all** promises are *resolved* but **not all are settled** (perhaps because the promise to which they were resolved is never settled either), right?

Comment: @Coder23 - You're right that not all promises are settled. But not all promises are resolved, either. For instance: `new Promise(() => {})`. That creates a promise that is never resolved or settled. Its fate isn't tied to any other promise, so it isn't resolved, and it will never be fulfilled or rejected, so it never settles. It will remain pending until it's garbage-collected. :-)

Comment: thanks @T.J. Crowder +1, so, a promise created with constructor (`new Promise(...`))always starts *unresolved*, right?

Comment: @Coder23 - The promise you receive from the constructor may be in any state or fate -- pending and unresolved, pending but resolved, fulfilled, rejected -- depending on what the executor function you pass the promise does. That function is called synchronously (its purpose is to start the asynchronous action the promise will report on), so if it calls `resolve` or `reject` synchronously (atypical, but possible) or it throws an error, that affects the state or fate of the promise before code calling the constructor receives it. Of course, that code can't tell, and shouldn't care. :-)

Comment: Now I understand it a little better, thank you @T.J. Crowder +1

Answer (score 7):

According to the [ECMAScript 2015 Language Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-objects)

> Promise Objects
>
> A Promise is an object that is used as a placeholder for the eventual results of a deferred (and possibly asynchronous) computation.
>
> Any Promise object is in one of three mutually exclusive states: fulfilled, rejected, and pending:
>   A promise p is fulfilled if p.then(f, r) will immediately enqueue a Job to call the function f.
>   A promise p is rejected if p.then(f, r) will immediately enqueue a Job to call the function r.
>   A promise is pending if it is neither fulfilled nor rejected.
>   A promise is said to be settled if it is not pending, i.e. if it is either fulfilled or rejected.
>
> A promise is resolved if it is settled or if it has been “locked in” to match the state of another promise. **Attempting to resolve or reject a resolved promise has no effect.** A promise is unresolved if it is not resolved. An unresolved promise is always in the pending state. A resolved promise may be pending, fulfilled or rejected.