# Is to safe to call the resolve() function of a promise several times?

Tags: javascript, promise, firebase-authentication

I already read the following questions. This is not a duplicate.

- [Is it safe to resolve a promise multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328073/is-it-safe-to-resolve-a-promise-multiple-times)
- [Call promise several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825069/call-promise-several-times)
- [Calling [promise's] resolve multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48438194/calling-promises-resolve-multiple-times)
- [What happens when a promise is resolved multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361492/what-happens-when-a-promise-is-resolved-multiple-times)

I created an initialiser (for firebase authentification) that resolves a promise the first time the user state changes. But the same function also run code the first and following times the state changes. My function looks like:

```
function initialize() {

  // Do initialization stuff
  // ...

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // Run the call back function every time the state changes
    onAuthStateChanged(auth,
      (user) => {
        // Do stuff every time the state change
        // ...
        console.log ('Hey, the state changed again');


        // Resolve the promise, only the first time
        resolve(user)
      },)
  }
}
```

I already tested the above code that seems to work properly. Of course, the promise is resolved only the first time, but this is **the expected behavior**.

As you noticed, the function `resolve()` may be called several times. According to what I read, `resolve()` become a deferred object once called. I'm not confident about what is a deferred object, and my question is : **is it safe to call the `resolve()` function several times?**. I'm aware the next calls will not have any effect, but I'm OK with that.

The other option I'm hesitating about is to call `onAuthStateChanged()` twice:

- once for the promise, once the promise is resolved, unsubscribe from this first `onAuthStateChanged()` listener
- a second one for the stuff that must be done every time the user state changes.

For those who are familiar with Firebase authentification, my question also relative to [How to wait for FirebaseAuth to finish initializing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231344/how-to-wait-for-firebaseauth-to-finish-initializing)

Comment: What is it about the fairly thorough answers to those other questions that misses key points about your question? The first linked question has a well-upvoted answer that explicitly says it's "100% fine". So what is it that you're worried about beyond that?

Comment: You should remove the auth state observer after you resolve the promise so you don't even have to worry about it at all.  That will stop the observer from triggering again.  onAuthStateChanged returns an unsubscribe function for this.  Please see the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) for more information.

Comment: If I'm right, the answer of the first question is about the point of view of the caller, not from the inside of the function

Comment: @DougStevenson You didn't get my point : I want both: promise the first time and code like notifications the other times. So I don't want to unsubscribe. Am I clear ?

Comment: You can record in your function whether or not you have already called resolve, and you still don't have to worry about it.

Comment: You can do both of these in a single `onAuthStateChanged` listener: 1) create a local variable `isFirst` that is `false` initially, and that you set to `true` once you've called the `resolve` of the promise, 2) call your custom callback each time.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I understand your solution with the flag. It is equivalent to the last section of my question. But the real point is : *is it really mandatory?* According to other comments it seems that not.

Comment: The first answer of the first marked duplicate says: "Additional calls to resolve() will not have any effect."

Comment: I through it was more about invocation, but OK, my bad.